# I cannot include the jar files in my project

Tags: java, jar, javac

I tried to use a sourceforge library in my program.
On my computer I use Eclipse, and I easily add the jar files to my project. 
Now, I want to move the code to another computer.

I tried an executable jar file, but the problem is I cannot debug it on the new computer.
So, I decided to move the source code and compile it there.

I tried the following but defeated in all of them: (all in Windows Command prompt)

1. Copy the jar files in the /lib/ext folder of my jre folder and add this folder to classpath
2. `javac -cp ".\lib\*.jar" src/*.java`
3. `javac -cp "./lib/*.jar" src/*.java`

In all of them the classes that are defined in the library jar files can not be recognized by java!
Actually the package doesn't find...

Any idea? Any stupid thing that I am doing?

Comment: The wild-card character would not work. Instead of 
` javac -cp ".\lib*.jar"` did you try really using `-cp fullpath_to_jar;fullpath_to_another_jar"` ?

Comment: I think you should just take your code (the directory where it is), open the project in the new machine and add the jars again the same way you did it in the first machine. Eclipse does not add anything to `lib/ext` and `javac` compiles things to be executed, not to move your code.

Comment: Also, this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3479466/422353

Comment: unless there is a real need, its a bad idea to add jars to the jre's ext directory. You can add a jar to the class path in the javac/java commands without copying it to the ext directory.

Comment: On the new machine, I don't want to install eclipse!

Comment: Also, I tried adding the jar files one by one in -cp! it doesn't recognize my classes!

Comment: and maybe it helps! the library that I want to include is HtmlUnit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct wildcard for matching all jars in a directory is just

```
-cp "dir/*"
```

Please see the ***Understanding class path wildcards*** section of this page: [Setting the classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Comment: I've read that document before! I did all the steps, and it doesn't work for me