# Specify location of App-Engine Connected Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, osx-mavericks, google-eclipse-plugin

Creating an `App-Engine Connected Android Project`, instead of using `default location`, I select the location where I want my project to be. But for some reason, only the android portion gets created in the location I specify. The App-Engine portion gets created in the default workspace. Does anyone know how I might get both the android and the app-engine portion into the correct location?

One solution might be the answer to: How do I move the location of an eclipse project?

My environment: osx-mavericks, juno eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer (my sleuthing skills are a bit wanting):

Right click on the Eclipse project in the Package Explorer, select Refactor, then select Move...

[Eclipse: moving project to another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479466/eclipse-moving-project-to-another-folder) (I up voted answer there)

Answer (score 0):

Delete it in Eclipse without deleting project content. Then move it somewhere and import to Eclipse again.