# Eclipse - how to rename project folder (on filesystem)

Tags: windows, eclipse

My workspace filesystem folder is currently `C:\work\Eclipse-Workspace_PROJ` and my code filesystem folder is `C:\work\PROJ`.

I want to rename `C:\work\PROJ` to `C:\work\PROJ-1` but last time I renamed it . . . bad things happened.

**QUESTION**

What are the steps to rename my code filesystem folder without corrupting things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer, according to the comments to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3991212/4784683) is that CDT doesn't have the ability to move projects on disk. :(

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Move` in the context menu of the Navigator view to move the project to a different folder.  This will move the project to a different folder without renaming it.

I sometimes get an error message that the move failed, but the only thing I can see is that the root folder at the old project location is not deleted. After deleting it no further problems occurred (Eclipse Neon.1 / 4.6.1).

Note that the `Move` function in CDT's Project Explorer view cannot do this.

Since your projects are not inside the workspace directory, they are not at their default location.  So renaming the project won't rename the folder.

Comment: What's "Navigator view"?

Comment: Window -> Show View -> Other -> General -> Navigator (deprecated). I don't know why it is deprecated nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

You should always rename things like Projects inside Eclipse using 'Refactor > Rename'.

There are many things in Eclipse that need to know about the rename, refactor will deal with updating them all.

If you are asking about renaming the Workspace folder then you do that outside of Eclipse (with Eclipse not running). Provided all the plug-ins you have installed in Eclipse are written correctly Eclipse should not care what the workspace folder is called.

Take a backup first if you are worried things may go wrong.

Comment: How do you rename the root directory of the code from inside Eclipse? The root CONTAINS the Eclipse projects. I cannot see the root folder inside my Eclipse project folder view.

Comment: Your question is not really clear what you are renaming. I have added info about renaming the workspace.

Comment: I clarified it.

Comment: I can rename the workspace folder but that's not my question. Question is: how do I rename the root folder inside of which my code resides?

Comment: In my original question, it would be renaming `PROJ` to `PROJ-1`, not `Eclipse-Workspace_PROJ`

Comment: was you able to find the solution, how did u renamed your project in file system from "PROJ" to "PROJ-1". I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy (not move/rename) the directory on the filesystem to the desired new location.
2. Delete the Eclipse .project file in that new directory
3. Delete the old project in Eclipse.
4. Create a new project in Eclipse at the new location.
5. Delete the old directory from the filesystem.