# Saving changes in my Eclipse editor window does not affect actual files

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

When I edit my .java files in the Eclipse editor (with Android Developer Tools), the changes are not actually registered in my source files. When I open up these same .java files in TextEdit it is clear that they have not been changed. So I have had to make all changes to my code in TextEdit, which is a bit difficult.

I discovered this last week, but it may have been occurring for much longer.

Has anyone ever had this happen? Is there a fix?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT: Update**

So I realize now that the reason Eclipse wasn't updating my files was that the Project Path had been automatically set to a different location than the workspace by the Egit plugin. Anyone know who to change the Project Path back from the git folder to the workspace folder? I'd prefer to do everything on the terminal.

Comment: If you are using GIT you need to use the way it has set up the project or it won't work!

Comment: you should be able to find this in:

"Eclipse change project files location" 
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430836/eclipse-change-project-files-location
or

"Eclipse: moving project to another folder" -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479466/eclipse-moving-project-to-another-folder?lq=1